# trouble finding the right django queryset for this

Tags: python, django

I have two models like this:

```
class Foo():
    name = CharField
    frequency = IntegerField

class Bar():
    thing = ForeignKey(Foo)
    content = TextField
```

I want to get a queryset that will be `Bar` objects sorted by a range of `Foo` objects. It obviously doesn't work, but it illustrates what I need.

```
Foo.objects.order_by('-frequency')[0:10].bar_set.all()
```

Comment: `Bar.objects.order_by('-thing__frequency')`?

Comment: the problem with that one is that it will give me a slice of 10 bar objects. I need bar objects based on a slice of 10 foo objects, which each may have multiple bar objects

Comment: So am I right in thinking your question is to retrieve the bar objects of the "top 10" ordered foo objects?

Comment: yes I need a queryset of bar objects of the top 10 foo objects

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this with the one query (operation), `Foo.objects.order_by('-frequency)[:10].prefetch_related('bar_set')` is the closest I can think of but then that requires you to loop through `foo`'s afterwards

Comment: do you need one query o could be two?

Comment: It is not a good practice, but if you really need to do this in one query you can use `extra` method on queryset

Comment: my final solution was to query `foo.order_by('frequency')` and then do another query like `bar.objects.filter(foo__in=query1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I am getting right what would you  like to achieve, try this:

```
objs = Bar.objects.filter(thing__pk__in=Foo.objects.all().order_by('-frequency').values_list('pk', flat=True)[:10])
```

Comment: That looks like the most efficient way. Thanks

Comment: Best wishes mate ;)